# '?' in middle of LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq

I cam across this line while going through some not that old code and don't understand why anyone would ever do it:

```
return dbStudents.MethodToReturnAllStudents()?.Select(x => new dtoStudent(x));
```

`MethodToReturnAllStudents` returns an `IEnumerable<SQLDomain.Student>` (`dtoStudent`) is in a different namespace -- all the `SQLDomain.Student` has been mapped from an `IDataRecord`.

Why would there be a `?` in the middle of this statement.  Will the LINQ `Select` try to do anything if `MethodToReturnAllStudents` returns `null`?

Is this just terrible code all around?

Side note: Either way, I am refactoring it to follow some alternative standards and to be much more readable.

Comment: This is not very old code. This is the C# 6.0 syntax to check for null. It is called [Null-Conditional Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I personally love code like this. Shows that the programmer knows the language well.

Comment: @steve duly noted -- i've been living in VB.net for a pretty long time

Comment: @USER_8675309 Do not refactor this. This is incredibly more readable than most other lines of code that would do the same thing.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/24/c-sharp-6-0-features/51/null-propagation#t=201608121957357872833

Comment: I think it is abuse of `?`. The methods like this shouldn't return `null`. They should return colletion (IEnumerabe) either empty or not.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan then just add a null coalesce at the end. I don't think it's abuse of ? at all, it's about as concise as the code can get and still is a very readable format

Comment: @D.Stewart, it depends...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not "old code", since this is a C#6 feature, the [Null Conditional Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx).  When used, it checks if the immediately preceding value is null before allowing property/method usage on that instance.  If it is null, it returns null.

In this scenario, you can translate this code to:

```
var students = dbStudents.MethodToReturnAllStudents();
if (students == null) return null;
return students.Select(x => new dtoStudent(x));
```

However, there is actually a larger potential issue with this code than the unfamiliar operator.

The general consensus is that `IEnumerable<T>` should never return null and, as such, should never need to be null checked.  It should always return a sequence that is either hydrated or empty.

That said, if this were in fact `List<T>` (or a null IEnumerable, although less common), this could be a real scenario (although I would still advocate for never returning null but rather an empty list).

You will have to decide as a development team if the [Null Conditional Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) is more succinct and readable.  Personally, I'm a fan of it, just not in this context since it is indicative of a larger design smell.

Answer (score 1):

It's not "terrible" code, but it's non-intuitive if you're not familiar with the syntax. I personally enjoy the less-verbose options. LINQ will stop if MethodToReturnAllStudents() returns null and just return that null. It's basically saying

```
var retVal = dbstudents.MethodToReturnAllStudents();
if(retVal == null) {
    return retVal;
} else {
    return retVal.Select(x => new dtoStudent(x));
}
```

Now as users have pointed out, it shouldn't return null as the caller is expecting an IEnumerable.

```
var retVal = dbstudents.MethodToReturnAllStudents();
if(retVal == null) {
    return new List<student>();
} else {
    return retVal.Select(x => new dtoStudent(x));
}
```

Using a null coalescing operator makes the code even more concise and still properly handles return types so it doesn't return null:

```
return dbStudents.MethodToReturnAllStudents()?.Select(x => new dtoStudent(x)) ?? new List<student>();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the Null Conditional Operator
[MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595(v=vs.140).aspx)

If dbStudents.MethodToReturnAllStudents() is null, it will return null instead of executing .Select(x => new dtoStudent(x))  which would result in a NullReferenceException.

Comment: `NullPointerException` is from Java, in C# it is `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: ACK, Thanks for catching that Hamlet.  I do that all the time.  I came from java roots and do am primarily C# now.  Ideally I never see that exception, but i still use some Java Names when I am not paying attention.